# How can i export the result set of an SQL Server stored procedure from one server into a table on another server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to export the result set of an SQL stored procedure on one server into a table on another server. Is there a way I can do this?

Please help.

Comment: `insert into another_database.dbo.a_table exec a_stored_procedure`

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi @sqirrel
Thank you for your valuable answer. I apologize, but I have made a mistake in asking the question. Could you please help me again?

Comment: Hi, if one of the provided answers helped your case please mark one as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes using a Linked Server is also an option (I try to avoid them for several reasons), especially if you have enough permissions *and* if you need to do this as a one off. Then your code would simply look like:

```
INSERT INTO somelinkedservername.somedatabasename.dbo.sometable
EXEC dbo.thesproc
```

But pending on the size of the resultset I prefer to use BCP and a fileshare to keep it simple and put the code in a SQL Agent job for overview:

```
bcp.exe "EXEC [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[uspGetEmployees] @managerId = 666" queryout "\\SomeShare\Temp\emps.txt" -ServerA -T -c
```

And then

```
bcp.exe "\\SomeShare\Temp\emps.txt" in -ServerB -T -c
```

Answer (score 0):

**Server Objects > Linked Server > Right Click > New Linked Server**

Data transfer= SELECT * FROM [Server Name].[Database Name].[Schema Name].[Table Name]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
execute ('EXECUTE DatabaseName.Schema.ProcedureName  @Parameter1=?,@Parameter2=?',@Parameter1Value,@Parameter2Value) at [ServerName]
```